# Memory leak in hibernate5 typeconfiguration registry class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Recently we have integrated hibernate 5 with our application upgrading it from hibernate 3.

After few months we have started seeing memory leak in typeconfiguration registry class in hibernate 5.

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/internal/TypeConfigurationRegistry.java

Particularly while creating new concurrent hashmap in the registerTypeConfiguration method.

1. The heap dump clearly states there is a leak.
2. Contents of this file during bootstrap indicates it contains all the dao classes.
3. Going by this there should be single set of DAO classes that gets registered during boot time and deregisters during shutdown.
4. But it is leaking memory which is concerning during runtime. Are there duplicate copies of DAO classes??

We use spring's localSessionFactoryBean to integrate with hibernate transaction manager.

Going by the localSessionFactoryBean documentation it is compatible with hibernate 5 which pegs the question why there is a leak?

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.23.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Configs:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"
          ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                    <<>>
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    <<>>
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please add your configuration and list of dependencies to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A few months back I faced a similar issue at work (leak from the same class but as part of a different hibernate workflow). Turns out that whenever Hibernate creates a `TypeConfiguration` it internally registers itself with the `TypeConfigurationRegistry` as shown in [this file](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6df82bb6a66ed1d9356dda11856f8da9e8d5e4a1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/spi/TypeConfiguration.java#L92). The only place I see the de-registration happening is as part of session factory close callback as [shown here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6df82bb6a66ed1d9356dda11856f8da9e8d5e4a1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/spi/TypeConfiguration.java#L213).

We were using the `SchemaExport` Hibernate API along with the HBM XML syntax. Given that there was no "official" way to clear out the in-built Hibernate cache, we adopted a workaround to grab a reference to the internal state of `TypeConfigurationRegistry` and clear it out.

Not the best way to go about it, I know, but just wanted to put this out there in case someone is in a similar situation like us.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this leak.

The typeconfigurationregistry was created everytime when the query got invoked.
Modified it to initialize during the startup which resolved the leak.

It was the developer responsibility to put it in startup which was missed. Hibernate 5.5 removed this registry.